Does the crop factor effect the aperture value as well?
Does the maximum aperture value also get multiplied by the crop factor if one attaches a full frame lens onto a APS-C sensor? This review of a full frame lens on a crop sensor DSLR states that the maximum aperture of f/1.4 will be reduced to f/2.1. (which is 1.4 multiplied by the crop factor of 1.5x)

Does this answer your question? Why do Full Frame lenses and crop body lenses exhibit the same crop factor when used on a crop body camera?

This question is similar to: Using FF lens on APS-C changes lens aperture value?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

TL;DR The aperture stays the same, independent of the sensor size, for both exposure as well as depth-of field purposes.
The aperture has two effects, which have to be considered individually:

exposure
depth of field (DOF)

For exposure, an f/1.4 is an f/1.4, no matter how large or small the sensor area in the camera body. (Effectively, the "crop sensor" is the same as taking a full-frame picture and cropping afterwards, and you need not adjust brightness/contrast when cropping in your favorite image editor, do you?)
For depth of field, it's a bit more complicated. With a given aperture and focal length, an off-focus scene element projects onto a circle of diffusion (COD) with a fixed size (determined by geometry).
Depth of field is based on the COD that you are willing to accept as "sharp", and here comes the influence of the sensor size, as you'd typically express that as fraction of the image size instead of absolute values. If you accept a 30µm circle as "sharp" with a full-frame sensor, you'd typically reduce that to 20µm with a crop sensor, as you have to do a bigger enlargement from the crop sensor.
While the same scene still gives you the same COD when measured in micro-meters, it gives you a larger one, measured in percent of the image size.
Requiring a smaller COD directly means a smaller DOF, and it scales rather linearly. So, if you start with a DOF formula created for a full-frame sensor, you'd adjust that by the crop factor.
Personally and for clarity, I'd use a DOF formula where I can explicitly insert my COD requirement. To me, this makes the relevant concepts explicit - even with a given sensor size, your COD requirements will vary depending on what you plan to do with the image later, use it for the internet or for a high-class magazine, so I'd stay away from any formula where the COD value isn't used explicitly.
I'd find it rather crude and confusing to express a tighter COD requirement through a modified "effective" aperture.

"For exposure, an f/1.4 is an f/1.4, no matter how large or small the sensor area..." Agree, and this determines the amount of light per unit area on the sensor. But if we compare a full frame and a crop sensor with the same # of pixels, the latter's pixels subtend a smaller area so would be exposed to less light. Does this mean the crop sensor's image would be darker?

@Not_Einstein No, not darker, but (typically) more noisy, as the camera producer implements a higher amplification to reach the same ISO sensitivity. For ISO sensitivity the question is: how many photons per square millimeter does the sensor need for a medium grey, With a smaller pixel size, a smaller percentage of these photons hit one given pixel cell, so more amplification is needed to achieve the same ISO value.

If images from both a smaller and larger sensor are to be viewed at the same display size, the higher enlargement ratio needed for the smaller sensor means all blur is enlarged by a greater factor compared to the larger sensor. That's why the circle of confusion is smaller for a smaller sensor: because it's assumed it will be enlarged by a greater factor to be displayed at "standard" size.

Mathematically, by definition, the aperture in the form of f/  has not changed with a crop factor.  The ratio of the focal length divided by the width of the aperture is the same.  This means all the exposure math is still the same.
However, the smaller sensor needs to be enlarged more to reach the same viewing size.  This will effectively reduce depth of field.  So, if out of focus areas are multiplied by the crop-factor because that's also the enlargement factor, then that might be roughly equivalent to multiplying the absolute aperture by the crop factor.  The absolute aperture is the inverse of the relative ( f/ ) aperture so you might be able to estimate depth of field by dividing the old f-stop by the crop factor. So an f-stop of f/1.4 for a given lens on full-frame might give a depth of field equivalent to "f/0.93" when used on a 1.5 crop sensor from the same taking location.
The angle of view will of course be different because of the crop, but you'd need to also change to a completely different wider lens to keep the same angle of view which invalidates the variables for the math anyway.

Photography was invented about 200 years ago. Cameras in the mid 1800’s needed to be large. By the early 1900’s technological advances permitted camera miniaturization. The motion picture industry adopted a film width of 35mm (1 3/8 inch) wide. The 35mm still camera was spawned due to the availability motion picture film. For a protracted time, the 35mm camera was King. Format 24mm height by 36mm length diagonal of this rectangular frame 43.3mm.
Technology marches on. The digital era introduces APS-C 16mm by 24mm with a diagonal of 28.8mm (Advanced Photo System – Classic format). Photographers flock to this format, more comfort as to carry and use. Just the beginning of digital camera miniaturization.
How to help the dedicated 35mm camera user more comfortably make these switches. Crop Factor (magnification factor) to the rescue. Sum-up the difference between 35mm and APS-C in a simplified way. 43.3 ÷ 28.8 = 1.5 (voila the crop factor).
Now the most popular 35mm camera lens is one with a focal length of 50mm. This lash-up is considered a “normal” lens as apposed to a wide-angle or telephoto. What lens mounted on an APS-C camera replicates this lash-up? 50 ÷1.5=30mm (rounded).  A good choice for a portrait lens for a 35mm camera is a 105mm. What focal length replicates this? 105 ÷ 1.5 = 70mm.
An APS-C has a 50mm lens mounted. What would be the equivalent for a 35mm camera? 50mm X 1.5 = 75mm.
What else can you do using the crop factor? Angle of view comparisons and conversion of depth-of-field tables. Warning some facts will need further assessment.
Also: The f-number method of lens speed comparison is universal. It is a ratio (focal ratio) and ratios are dimensionless. Any lenes with an f-number that matches another, even if mounted on some other format, passes the same brilliance thus the lens setting for exposure is identical.
A variable focal length zoom with a constant aperture works because the front lens element group acts as a magnifier. It causes the diameter of the entrance pupil to appear to change its diameter with the zoom. This action causes the lens to change its light gathering ability as the focal length changes with the zoom. This is very clever. A tip of the hat to the constant aperture lens designers.

If you take the same image, and view it in the same way as with a full frame sensor, then the effect of the f# is also multiplied. This affects the depth of field (DOF) in the final image as well as the exposure; but it does not affect the other exposure settings (SS/ISO).
The reason crop factor affects DOF is that in order to record the same image from within the cropped center of a lens' field of view you must move farther away. And increasing the subject distance has a greater effect on DOF than aperture does (If you did not increase the distance, the DOF would decrease instead).
The reason it affects the exposure (total light recorded) is because the subject (source of light) is being recorded smaller from a greater distance. The inverse square law dictates that the intensity of light falling on a certain area (lens opening) decreases over distance (because it spreads out). I.e. a light bulb recorded physically smaller on a physically smaller sensor is less light. However, because it is also physically smaller, the light per area on the sensor occupied by the light bulb (exposure settings) does not change (also the inverse square law).

Edit:
Conversely, to record the same image on a larger sensor, from the same distance with the same settings, requires a longer lens at the same F#. Because F# is a ratio of opening diameter to focal length that means the actual aperture opening (entrance pupil) is larger; which means the lens transmits more light (in order to record the light bulb larger).
The factor of more/less total light comes into play when the images are output/viewed at the same size (signal to noise ratio/image noise).

Can you clarify your third paragraph? You're giving the reason crop factor affects exposure but end by saying exposure doesn't change (with crop factor).

@Not_Einstein, there are two aspects to exposure, light per area and total light. The settings which affect exposure are dictated by light per area. But the factor dictating image noise is total light (per sensor/per subject). Say the crop sensor and the large sensor have the same sized pixels, and each pixel at full exposure has collected 100 photons. The FF sensor has 46 million pixels and the crop sensor has 14 million; which has collected more light (photons)? the FF has 4600 million and the crop has 1400 million.

So if you view the two images at the same physical output size, that spreads the light per area recorded (signal/noise/information) out more for the smaller sensor; and that results in greater image noise. The same thing happens if you crop and enlarge the FF image in post... the light per area as viewed decreases and the image appears to be noisier. I.e. you are cropping away the additional light potential the larger sensor had because you didn't take advantage of it.

I edited the answer to help clarify...
